# MongoDB Index ensureIndex Time to Refresh

Tags: mongodb, casbah

I created a multi-key compound index via Casbah (Scala library for Mongo):

`db.collection.ensureIndex(MongoDBObject("Header.records.n" -> 1) ++ MongoDBObject("Header.records.v" -> 1) ++ MongoDBObject("Header.records.l" -> 1))`

Then, via the Mongo Shell I had performed a `db.collection.find(...).explain` where the `nScannedObjects` exceeded the `db.collection.count()`. Looking at the Mongo [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#should-you-run-ensureindex-after-every-insert), it appears that ensureIndex needs to be called **once**, and then any writes will force an update of the index.

However, I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547526/ensureindex-in-mongodb) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001139/409976) that it's only required to call `db.collection.ensureIndex(...)` once.

**EDIT**

```
>db.collection.find( {"Header.records" : {$all : [ 
{$elemMatch: {n: "Name", v: "Kevin", 
                         "l" : { "$gt" : 0 , "$lt" : 15}} }]}}, 
             {_id : 1}).explain()
    {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor         
     Header.records.n_1_Header.records.v_1_Header.records.l_1",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "n" : 4098,
            "nscannedObjects" : 9412,
            "nscanned" : 9412,
            "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 9412,
            "nscannedAllPlans" : 9412,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nYields" : 0,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "millis" : 152,
            "indexBounds" : {
                    "Header.records.n" : [
                            [
                                    "Name",
                                    "Name"
                            ]
                    ],
                    "Header.records.v" : [
                            [
                                    "Kevin",
                                    "Kevin"
                            ]
                    ],
                    "Header.records.l" : [
                            [
                                    0,
                                    1.7976931348623157e+308
                            ]
                    ]
            },
            "server" : "ABCD:27017"
```

Note that **nScanned** (9412) > **count**(4248).

```
> db.collection.count()
4248
```

Why?

Comment: the update is atomic to the documents own update, it is instant basically

Comment: but, why am I looking at `db.collection.count()` to be **4000**, but running `db.collection.find(...).explain()` shows `nScannedObjects` too be **9000**.

Comment: can you provide the actual explain? It sounds like a badly used index

Comment: `db.claims.find( {"recordss" : {$all : [ {$elemMatch: {n:   "Name", v: "Kevin", "l" : { "$gt" : 0 , "$lt" : 15}} }]}}, {_id : 1}).expla
in()` I'm using a n-v-l database structure similar to this post - http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/47178201123/mongodb-indexing-tip-3-too-many-fields-to-index-use

Comment: can you edit your question with the explain results?

Comment: To answer your first question multikey indexes produce one value per entry in the index as such this means that a single document can take up more more than one space in the index which explains `nscanned` but `nScannedObjects` should relate to documents, I'll need to test this some more

Comment: @Sammaye, looks like the answer might be `About nscanned exceeding the count, that is probable since you actually have way more index entries than you have documents: each item in your list is an index entry.` source - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10436?focusedCommentId=445006&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-445006.

Comment: Yeah that's I said, though didn't know nscannedobjects was just a counter, that doesn't make it very reliable...

Comment: Why's it not reliable?

Comment: Cos you assume it will dictate how many unique documents it had to look at it, if it counts duplicate documents you can't reliably judge when index usage is going hay wire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About "nscanned" exceeding the count, that is probable since you actually have way more index entries than you have documents: each item in your list is an index entry. It seems like here you have on average 2 items in list per document. "nscannedObjects" follows the same principle since that counter is incremented whenever a document is looked at, even if the same document was already looked at earlier as part of the same query.

Comment: So, if I have 2000 documents. On average, each document has an array of 3 sub-documents. If, of the 2000 documents, 2/3 sub-documents match `n: "Name", v: "Kevin", l: {$gt: 0, $lt: 15}`, then `nScanned` should equal **4000** (2000 documents times 2 sub-documents matching per document)?